# Correct title in LaTex specific documentclass

Tags: titles

[image][image][image]I have a problem with a title of my Research statement. I used the code below however two lines are appeared below title which I want to remove them. Could anybody help me?

```
\documentclass[article]{elsarticle}
\title{Ahello world}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

xxxxxxxxxx





\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you prepare a paper that you would like to submit to an Elsevier journal? If not, I wouldn't use this specific documentclass but go for a standart `article` instead.

Comment: Thank you. No this one is not for that but then I have problem with citation. Could you please let me know hoe can I change this code then?

Comment: What exactly is the citation problem? Please show an example that produces the unexpected output and a description of what you expect instead.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}` will just do fine for the moment and there will be no horizontal lines. You might however see the current date added below the title. Which bibliography style to use depends purely on the desired output.

Comment: Exactly I changed the code now I want to remove date. Also, everything is in the center I mean the article is written in the center of the page. please look at photo I attached above again

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\title{XXXX}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Natural fibers have become prevalent in different real-life applciations due to their sustainable and environmental friendly characeristics as well as high stiffness-weigth ratio, thus providing an appropriate alternative for synthetic composite materials \cite{ramamoorthy2015review}.





\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}

Comment: You could use `\date{}` to remove the date. Does "everything is in the center" refer to the title being shifted downwards when using the `article` class or is it about the horizontal alignment of the title?

Comment: Thanks horizontal alignment my friend

Comment: Thanks horizontal alignment my friend. i uploaded the new one above. I think it is not Ok. isn't it? The title is not Ok and I am not sure about the written part. I mean is it in the center or it is normal?

Comment: The title is centered with respect to the text following it. And the text is centered with respect to the page. I must admit, I see no problem here. Is your question about the indentation of the text (The small horizontal white space just before "Naturalfibers")?

Comment: Thank you again. No I meant the written part and the title it seems that they are in the center and the margin is too much for left and right side, No?

Comment: This site does not work well when the question changes from its original.  If we've solved your original question, then it may be best to ask a new question, link to this one, and include a minimal working example that shows the problem you're having.

Comment: @Turkan, easiest way to get rid of the date is to define it as blank `\date{}`. But the space stays.